# Iterator for loop logic

Tags: android, loops, iterator

I have a problem that I can't think through. 
I have a list of phone numbers, which are represented as: A user has the app
I also have a treemap of all contacts in my phone 
I want to compare all users that have the app to my treemap of contacts, so that if the user has the app - i can add them as a friend, but if they don't then I can send out a text invite. Here's what i have, but it's not working:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = contacts.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
                for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                    String userNumber = Helper.formatNumber(users.get(i).getString("phone"));
                    if(pairs.getValue().equals(userNumber)) { //they have the app
                        contact_data.add(new Contact(pairs.getKey().toString(), pairs.getValue().toString(), true));
                    } else { //they don't have the app
                        contact_data.add(new Contact(pairs.getKey().toString(), pairs.getValue().toString(), false));
                    }
                }
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
```

Comment: Elaborate "it's not working". What error message are you getting? What is the current outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you check to see if a user matches the contact you are currently looking at, you add that user. It seems like you only want to add one user per contact.

One approach would be to add a boolean "found" before your for loop and initialize it to false. Once you find a user who has the app, set this boolean to true. Put the else branch labelled "//they don't have the app" after the for loop and only run it if(!found). This will ensure that you only add one contact data per contact.